# What is the name of this item and how to get it back?

Tags: interface

I think I pressed an unintended keyboard shortcut and this cursor thing

[image: Cursor]

in 3D view disappeared. What is the name of it and how to get it back?

I am already in object mode, not in edit mode.

**Edit**

From the comment, it seems that it is called "manipulator". However, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does not show it.

Comment: Ctrl + Space is the shortcut for hiding and showing the manipulator

Comment: You can turn it on and off from the UI as well:
http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/manipulators.html

Comment: Pros call it widget or just thingy ;)

Comment: @Jerryno lol, pros don't know the name because they  don't use it. It just gets in the way of what you're trying to click on, and keyboard shortcuts are faster. :-p But back in the day it helped me understand the concept of a selection's Median Point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like I have disabled all manipulators like this:

[image: Manipulators disabled]

in which case pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does not have an effect.

Turning on at least one of them like this:

[image: Manipulators enabled]

brings the manipulator back.

Hovering over the item does not show a keyboard shortcut, so it must have been a mis-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-click instead of an unintended keyboard shortcut.